# Feasibility Study Format on SDLC

Tags: sdlc

Is there a specific format for a feasibility study in SDLC? If so, do you know any sources where I can find more information about this? or can you show me at least an outline of what it should contain?

Comment: By SDLC to you mean Software Development Life Cycle? If so what kind of study are you talking about. More information may help get this discussion started. (From @Carlosfocker).

Comment: Do you mean whether you should adopt a life cycle (you have one whether it's formal or not) or something else? Not really sure what you are after here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the creative commons OpenSDLC http://openSDLC.org it has great sections on strategic planning as part of the early release gates.

> [*SDLC IT Strategic Planning*](http://opensdlc.org/mediawiki/index.php?title=SDLC_SOP_1006_-_Strategic_Planning) This document provides an overview of the iterative strategic planning process of IT. Information Technology Strategic planning in an continuous process managed through a project management methodology. Major changes in the business environment (internal and/or external) will lead to a re-assessment of the IT Strategy to ensure it is fully aligned with the business strategy for the company...

Answer (score 1):

I would have thought a feasibility study is part of your project management. Once that is completed you would start on your SDLC with analysis, design..etc. Or you may include pm in your SDLC according to company practice.

further to an answer, a feasibility study might include all project related costs, user acceptance, affects on company image, your ability to complete the project, time related risks etc..

Answer (score 0):

I would tend to regard a feasibility study as a project in it's own right, separate to the project it *may* trigger if the feasibility study is successful.

So ultimately I'd start it exactly as I'd start any other project - outline what a successful outcome looks like so you know where you're heading, break it down into tasks, outline the quality metrics (potentially fairly low though you might want test input to validate the programmers findings).

Once you've got that you can select your SDLC - either waterfall or agile would work - and plan as appropriate.

But the key thing with a feasibility study is to be clear what your goals are (that is we wish to prove concept X and concept Y can be achieved within timescale X) and make sure you've got the mechanisms in place to measure them so you know when you've either succeeded or failed.

And remember, finding something isn't feasible is a valid outcome from a study and not a failure on the part of the team involved - if everything that came out of them was found to be feasible then you'd have to ask questions why they were necessary.